# Hyphenation of words containing slash

Tags: hyphenation

How can I tell LaTeX to automatically split up the german word

```
Kontrast/Rausch-Verhältnis
```

into

`Kontrast/Rausch-|Ver|hält|nis`

LaTeX complains that "/" is not a letter.

Comment: `Kontrast/Rausch-Ver\-hält\-nis`

Comment: Would you allow breaking at the slash? If not, use `Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis`

Comment: please give us an MWE showing what you are trying to do. There was not one word about `nomencl` in your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A hyphen allowing hyphenation in the following word is obtained in `babel-german` with `"=`; if you want also to allow breaking at `/`, use `\slash` for it:

```
Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis}
```

with no break at `/`, or

```
Kontrast\slash Rausch"=Verhältnis
```

if breaking at `/` is allowed.

Here's a document showing the various possibilities; the narrow `\parbox` is just to force TeX into hyphenating as much as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}Kontrast/Rausch-Verhältnis}

\bigskip

\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis}

\bigskip

\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}Kontrast\slash Rausch"=Verhältnis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use this for defining global rules? \hyphenation{Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis} gives LaTeX error "Not a letter"?

Comment: @Robinaut You can't.

Comment: My original problem is that using the `nomencl` package for creating a nomenclature the hyphenation rules above are completely ignored.

Comment: Can you also write `Kontrast\slash{}Rausch\hyp{}Verhältnis`?

Comment: @user Yes, if `\hyp` does the same as `"=`

Answer (score 4):

For hyphenation in German, I would recommend the shorthands of the babel package. I inserted your desired result (`2.`), the two versions mentioned in comments (`3.` and `4.`) and the version, I would use (`5.`). This version forbids a hyphenation which is too close to the hyphen (one syllable to the left and right). In my opinion, such close consecutive hyphens make the word difficult to read. If you want to allow the hyphenation behind the slash as well, you can use the last (`6.`) version:

```
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{0.3cm} % for testing
\begin{document}

% without treatment
1. Kontrast/Rausch-Verhältnis   

% your desired result
2. \mbox{Kontrast}/Rausch-Ver"-hält"-nis

% egregs version from comment
3. Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis

% Sigurs version from comment
4. Kontrast/Rausch-Ver\-hält\-nis

% my recommendation
5. Kon"-trast/Rausch-Verhält"-nis

% allowing hypenation after the slash
6. Kon"-trast/""Rausch-Verhält"-nis

    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV1}{Kontrast/Rausch-Verhältnis} % same as above
    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV2}{\mbox{Kontrast}/Rausch-Ver"-hält"-nis} % same as above
    %\nomenclature[Strings]{KRV3}{Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis} % not working. Replace with:
    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV3}{Kon"-trast/Rausch-Ver"-hält"-nis} or by:
    %\nomenclature[Strings]{KRV3}{Kontrast/Rausch""=Verhältnis}
    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV4}{Kontrast/Rausch-Ver\-hält\-nis} % same as above
    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV5}{Kon"-trast/Rausch-Verhält"-nis} % same as above
    %\nomenclature[Strings]{KRV6}{Kon"-trast\""Rausch-Verhält"-nis} % not working. Replace /"" by \slash{}
    \nomenclature[Strings]{KRV6}{Kon"-trast\slash{}Rausch-Verhält"-nis}

    \printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**:

as requested, I inserted these versions into items of the `nomencl` package. Two of them did not work. See the comments in code. I replaced these two version by working ones.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working with the `nomecl` package

Comment: @Robinaut Please see my update. All versions will now work and you just have to choose one. If this is not working, you will have to give us an MWE.

Comment: Just for reference: Here is my [Spickzettel](http://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/georg.verweyen/silbentrennung.html) for such things.

Answer (score 3):

Rethink the spelling: The recommended spelling is Kontrast-Rausch-Verhältnis with two hyphens. No need for a fancy slash here.

Then of course one of the following packages is indicated

`\usepackage{ngerman}`

or

`\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Also do not forget the following package (otherwise Verhältnis will not hyphenate)

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

and finally write

`Kontrast"=Rausch"=Verhältnis`

Comment: That's a good point...