# how to get latex to hyphenate a word that contains a slash?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm using 'und/oder' (German for 'and/or') in one of my texts (I know it's not nice :)). Latex separates it 'und/o-der' which is not nice. Using \mbox fixes that problem.

Trying to find a general solution like

```
\hyphenation{und/oder}
```

does not work though: 'Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. \hyphenation{und/'.

What would be the correct way to archive this?

---

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash/8649145), but somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Don't write `und/oder`; instead, write `und\slash oder`. This will allow TeX to insert a line break (without hyphenation character, of course) after "und/".
- Do insert the instruction

  ```
  \hyphenation{oder}
  ```

  in the preamble of your document. This will prevent the highly questionable `o-der` hyphenation from happening in the first place.

A separate remark: Your document appears to be (mainly?) in German. If so, are you loading the `babel` package with the option `ngerman` (or `german`, if you adhere to older rules of orthography)? Enabling `babel` in this manner will inform TeX that the applicable hyphenation rules are for German, not English.

Comment: If you have a custom hyphenation pattern for the first word, you have to include the slash as well: `\hyphenation{Clang} \hyphenation{Clang/}`.

Comment: @corvus_192 - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: In my case, the first part of the word (before the slash) is "Clang" (the C compiler). Latex by default hyphenates this as "Clan-g", which is wrong. So I added a custom rule `hyphenation{Clang}`. I ran into the problem that before a slash, "Clang" was hyphenated as "Clan-g", even though I had specified the custom hyphenation pattern. The problem is that the pattern "Clang" is not applied to "Clang/", so I had to add the rule `hyphenation{Clang/}`, so that the word is correctly hyphenated before a slash. I was commenting here in case someone else has this issue.

Comment: @corvus_192 - Thanks for providing this piece of follow-up information. You've now made me curious, though: have you set `\righthyphenmin=1` by ahy chance? If not, TeX should *never* even contemplate hyphenating the word "clang" as "clan-g". (For reference: For English language hyphenation rules, one usually sets `\righthyphenmin=3` and `\lefthyphenmin=2`.)

Comment: I can't figure out how I got "Clan-g", maybe I'm misremembering. However "Clan-g/" definitely occurs. I'm using babel with the ngerman options. Babel sets `righthyphenmin` to 2 for german (see [here](https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/903b9ca5685ec0b5c432fbd1d211a7df50bfc29d/locale/de/babel-de.ini#L153)). I think latex is counting the slash as a character, so "g/" can be on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and use the `""` shorthand.  From `ngermanb.pdf`:

> **2 Shorthands**
>
> `""` a breakpoint that does not output a hyphen sign if the line break
>   is performed (useful for compound words with hyphen, e.g.
>   (Un-)""Sinn).

Code borrowed from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193590/76063):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}und/oder}} \par\bigskip
\fbox{\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}und/""oder}} \par\bigskip
\fbox{\parbox{24pt}{\hspace{0pt}Kontrast/""RauschVerhältnis}}
\end{document}
```

> [image]