# What is the difference between "= and \hyp{}?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, hyphenat

Sometimes I see questions talking about using `"=`, others just use `\hyp{}`. Are they the same thing?

For example, on these questions you find both `"=` and `\hyp` use:

1. [Hyphenation of words containing slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193587/hyphenation-of-words-containing-slash)
2. [LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/latex-not-hyphenating-properly-text-running-off-page)
3. [How to hyphenate a reference that has a lastname with a hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98873/how-to-hyphenate-a-reference-that-has-a-lastname-with-a-hyphen)

I tried creating this minimal example, but `"=` is not working:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As your question gives so little explicit information I have no idea but I doubt it. Can you give more details about these "questions" and, ideally, a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)?

Comment: I added example questions I could find using both.

Comment: For me the equal signs display as `=` but `-` and `\hyp` seem pretty much the same. Looking in `hyphenat.sty`, from the [hyphenat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) package, the `\hyp` command is a robust command that is defined to be `\ifmmode-\else\BreakableHyphen\fi`. So, `\hyp` and `-` are the almost same except inside mathematics.

Comment: To get the `"=` shorthand directive to work, you must replace `\usepackage[english]{babel}` with `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} \useshorthands{"} \addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}`. See [babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27198/5001) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `"=` shorthand directive to work in your document, you must replace

```
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
```

with

```
 \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
 \useshorthands{"} 
 \addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

See [babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27198/5001) for more information on this subject.

Once this adjustment is made, it would appear that `\hyp{...}` and `"=` perform very similarly. The `"=` would appear to be a lot easier to use in practice, though.

The vertical frame lines in the following screenshot are placed by the `showframe` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{hyphenat} % for "\hyp" macro

%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27198/5001:
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\useshorthands{"} 
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\usepackage{showframe,microtype} % just for this example
\begin{document}
*

Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

Encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding.

Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined behaviour of `"=` in `babel` and it's language dependent (but in most cases it's a hard hyphen). Instead of loading `ngerman`, you can define it directly in the following way:

```
\useshorthands{"} 
\defineshorthand{"=}{\babelhyphen{hard}}
```